# Companion objects in C++

Tags: c++, scala, companion-object

I was reading about the companion objects (or classes) in Scala and I'd like to know if there's a similar concept in C++ as well?  E.g. to have the option of using some methods of the class without creating an actually instance (companion object), or using the normal class?

Comment: I don't know scala so I can't contrast at all. In `c++` you can call static class member functions without an instance.

Comment: C++ has no companion objects, though different languages have different solutions to the same problems. What problem do you want to solve with a companion object in C++?

Comment: Can you explain those in a way that doesn't require knowing Scala?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat One way to think about *the companion object of a class* in Scala, is as the new home for any static methods you might have written in that same class, in Java.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Scala has two major kinds of program structuring mechanisms: classes and objects. (It also has traits but for the purpose of this discussion the distinction between classes and traits is irrelevant.) Scala has *no static state*, i.e. there are no class methods, static fields, or whatever you want to call them. Other than that, classes and traits are just like classes in any vaguely classical OO-ish language. Objects are similar to object literals in ECMAScript: an object defines both a type and an instance where the object is the singleton instance of its type.

Comment: The closest thing are probably static methods.

Comment: @JörgWMittag So this sounds like static functions with extra steps.

Comment: In C++ terms, you can think of it as a class with an unspeakable name that gets automatically instantiated exactly once. A *companion* object, specifically, is an object which a) has the same name as a trait or class and b) is defined in the same compilation unit. These two features together make an object a "companion". The main feature of a companion object is that the class and the object in the companionship are allowed to call each other's private methods. A common use case is to make the constructor of a class and its setters private and then have a companion object with a public factory